# XPath: Appending text only to the last text() occurrence (regardless of how deeply nested) while copying all XML.

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Using XSLT on an XML file, my goal is to copy all XML while appending a snippet of text ("(PDF)" in this example) to only the last bit of text present in a particular tag regardless of how deeply nested that next is. I've managed to take care of most of the edge cases and gotten it close, but there's still one instance that's giving me trouble. I'm sure there's also a way to do this more efficiently so any tips are appreciated.

**XML**

```
<links>
    <a href="something.pdf">This is a PDF file</a>
    <a href="something.PDF">
        <span>
            <b>This</b> is a PDF file
        </span>
    </a>
    <a href="something.pdF">
        <div>
            <span>
                This is a PDF file
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="something.pdf">
        <div class="something">
            <span>
                This is a <i>PDF</i> file
            </span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="something.pDf">
        <div class="something">
            <div>
                <div>
                    Test Text
                    <div>
                        This is a <i>PDF</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</links>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:param name="pdf-append" select="'(PDF)'"/>

    <xsl:template match="a['.pdf' = substring(translate(@href,'PDF','pdf'), string-length(@href) - 3)]/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(),' ', $pdf-append)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a['.pdf' = substring(translate(@href,'PDF','pdf'), string-length(@href) - 3)]//node()[last()]/text()[last()]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(),' ', $pdf-append)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Result**

```
<links>
<a href="something.pdf">This is a PDF file (PDF)</a>
   <a href="something.PDF">
      <span>
         <b>This</b> is a PDF file
         (PDF)</span>
   </a>
   <a href="something.pdF">
      <div>
         <span>
                This is a PDF file
             (PDF)</span>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="something.pdf">
      <div class="something">
         <span>
                This is a <i>PDF</i> file
             (PDF)</span>
      </div>
   </a>
   <a href="something.pDf">
      <div class="something">
         <div>
            <div>
                    Test Text
                     (PDF)<div>
                        This is a  (PDF)<i>PDF (PDF)</i>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</links>
```

The last `<a>` is the problem: ideally "(PDF)" would only appear within the the last `<i>` tag (e.g. `This is a <i>PDF (PDF)</i>`). So the questions is: how can I fix that last instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="pdf-append" select="' (PDF)'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="a" select="ancestor::a" />
    <xsl:variable name="href" select="$a/@href" />
    <xsl:variable name="extension" select="substring(translate($href,'PDF','pdf'), string-length($href) - 3)" />
    <xsl:variable name="last-text" select="$a/descendant::text()[last()]" />

    <xsl:if test="$extension='.pdf' and generate-id()=generate-id($last-text) ">
        <xsl:value-of select="$pdf-append"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```